# Не получается остановить IntentService

Tags: android, android-service

У меня в сервисе крутиться вот такой вот счетчик:

```
 private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mCurrentMilis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mElapsedTime = mCurrentMilis - mLastMilis;
        mLastMilis = mCurrentMilis;
        mTotalMilis += mElapsedTime;

        responseResumeClick(mTotalMilis);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
```

И при попытке остановить сервис следующим способом

```
ChronometrService.stop(getApplicationContext());

public static void stop(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChronometrService.class);
    context.stopService(intent);
}
```

или так

```
stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ChronometrService.class));
```

Он все равно продалжает рабоатать. Как можно его остановить?

Полный код сервиса

```
public class ChronometrService extends IntentService {

public static final String ACTION_RESUME_CLICK = "resumeClick";
public static final String ACTION_STOP_SERVICE = "stopService";
public static final String RESPONSE_RESUME_CLICK = "responseResumeClick";
public static final String EXTRA_PARAM = "EXTRA_PARAM";
private static final String TAG = "ChronometrService";


private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private static long mTotalMilis;
private long mLastMilis;
private long mElapsedTime;
private long mCurrentMilis;

public ChronometrService() {
    super("ChronometrService");
}

public static void resumeClick(Context context, long totalMilis) {
    mTotalMilis = totalMilis;
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChronometrService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_RESUME_CLICK);
    context.startService(intent);
}

public static void stopService(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChronometrService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_STOP_SERVICE);
    context.startService(intent);
}



@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, action);
        switch (action) {
            case ACTION_RESUME_CLICK:
                mLastMilis = mElapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                sendUpdatesToUI.run();
                break;

            case ACTION_STOP_SERVICE:
                //todo stop method
        }

    }
}

private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mCurrentMilis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mElapsedTime = mCurrentMilis - mLastMilis;
        mLastMilis = mCurrentMilis;
        mTotalMilis += mElapsedTime;

        responseResumeClick(mTotalMilis);
        System.out.println(TAG + " mTotalMilis =  " + mTotalMilis);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100); // 0.1 seconds
    }
};


public void responseResumeClick(long totalMilis) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RESPONSE_RESUME_CLICK);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PARAM, totalMilis);
    LocalBroadcastManager bm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    bm.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: `крутиться вот такой вот счетчик` - в отдельном потоке? Если да, то поток надо остановить, иначе он никогда и не умрет.

Comment: @metalurgus  а как это сделать применительно к моему коду!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у Вас действительно все сделано как `IntentService`, от его и не нужно останавливать, он как правило после выполнения `onHandleIntent()` больше ничего не делает, т.е. останавливается.

Крутится в Вашем коде `Handler`, как его остановить, без знания всего кода сказать практически невозможно. Обычно это делают как-то так:

```
private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    if (isRunning) {
        mCurrentMilis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mElapsedTime = mCurrentMilis - mLastMilis;
        mLastMilis = mCurrentMilis;
        mTotalMilis += mElapsedTime;

        responseResumeClick(mTotalMilis);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
  }
};
```

**UPDATE**. Не считаю такой подход идеологически верным, потому что `IntentService` для таких задач не предназначен, но вот фикс.

```
private static boolean isRunning;
.....
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  if (intent != null) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    Log.d(TAG, action);
    switch (action) {
        case ACTION_RESUME_CLICK:
            mLastMilis = mElapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            isRunning = true;
            sendUpdatesToUI.run();
            break;

        case ACTION_STOP_SERVICE:
            isRunning = false;
            break;
    }

  }
}
```

Код `Runnable` как в начале ответа.

Один нюанс. Если после `STOP` придет `RESUME` через время, меньшее чем 100мс, есть вероятность, что появится вторая копия `Runnable`. Об этом надо позаботится. Если же эти события генерит пользователь, то вероятность практически нулевая.

Comment: добавил код сервиса